# GAPING OF SQL TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm Nguyen Van Dung,

I found difficulty with checking gap of SERIAL number, each number is a complex of chars and digits
I have a table with following 
data

```
SERIAL NUMBER
3LBCF007787
3LBCF007788
3LBCF007789
3LBCF007790
3LBCF007792
3LBCF007793
3LBCF007794
3LBCF007795
```

Now I really want to display an output table  as below structure

```
START_SERIAL    END_SERIAL
3LBCF007787     3LBCF007790
3LBCF007792     3LBCF007795
```

Please support me by querying SQL server

Thank you very much

Comment: Have a look at LAG and LEAD window functions. If you use SQL Server 2012 they should be first in your research list

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the format of `serial_number` is fixed, here is one way of doing it

```sql
WITH split AS
(
  SELECT serial_number, 
         LEFT(serial_number, 5) prefix, 
         CONVERT(INTEGER, RIGHT(serial_number, 6)) num
    FROM table1 
), ordered AS
(
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY prefix, num) rn,
         MIN(num) OVER (PARTITION BY prefix) mnum
    FROM split
)
SELECT MIN(serial_number) start_serial,
       MAX(serial_number) end_serial
  FROM ordered
 GROUP BY num - mnum - rn
```

Output:

```
| START_SERIAL |  END_SERIAL |
|--------------|-------------|
|  3LBCF007787 | 3LBCF007790 |
|  3LBCF007792 | 3LBCF007795 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a825e/23)** demo

Comment: @DũngNguyễnVăn You're quite welcome. If it was what you were looking for please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.